# Extracting first element from vectors in a list

Tags: r

If I have a list of vectors, how can I get the first element of each vector in another list as shown by `end_result`?

```
data_list <- list(c("hello","world"),
                  c("goodbye","everyone"))

end_result <- list(c("hello","goodbye"))
```

Comment: `list(unlist(data_list)[c(TRUE, FALSE)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applys the `[` function to each element of `data_list` (with the argument `1` to get the first entry), simplifies the result into a vector, and then wraps that vector into a new list.

```
> data_list |> sapply(`[`,1) |> list()
[[1]]
[1] "hello"   "goodbye"
```